# What does "$(NO_EXPORT :+-n" do?

Tags: bash

I am trying to understand what is meaning in uci.sh under openwrt

An error occurs at line 30.

```
if [-z "$CONFIG_APPEND" ]; then
..
 export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n} CONFIG_LIST_STATE=
...
fi
```

What does `export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n}` do in the example above?

Question 2:

```
append() {
  local var="$1"
  local value="$2"
  local sep="${3:- }"

  eval "export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n} -- \"$var=\${var:+\${var}\${value:+\$sep}}\$value\""
}
```

What is meaning of eval `"export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n} --`?

Answer (score 2):

`${NO_EXPORT:+-n}` evaluates to `-n` if `NO_EXPORT` is set, otherwise to the empty string.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html for all these variable expansions.

So this:

```
export ${NO_EXPORT:+-n} CONFIG_LIST_STATE=
```

is almost equivalent to this:

```
if [ "$NO_EXPORT" ]
then
    export -n CONFIG_LIST_STATE=
else
    export CONFIG_LIST_STATE=
fi
```

(The difference is that the first form also gracefully handles the case where `NO_EXPORT` is not set, but the second form would fail if `NO_EXPORT` was not set and `set -u` had been used to treat undefined variables as errors.)

The `eval` is the same, it's just using an `eval` to expand the local variables to compute the command to perform.

Comment: More precisely, `${NO_EXPORT:+-n}` expands to `-n` if `NO_EXPORT` is set to a non-empty string, and to the empty string if `NO_EXPORT` is unset or is set to the empty string.